# I've tested in Chrome, do I need to test in Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, webkit

I've tested in Chrome, do I need to test in Safari?

Comment: Tricky... your subject ask if you need to do more testing, and the body asks if it is enough. If I say "YES", what question have I said yes to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've noticed Safari handles Asian characters better than Chrome.
Also Chrome and Safari rely on the same Webkit for rendering pages, but their Javascript engines are totally different, so if you use Javascript in your pages you need to check both.

Answer (score 7):

[Browsershots](http://www.browsershots.org/) will send you screen shots of your page in just about every browser ever made.

Comment: that is a great tool, but unfortunately there's a lot more to testing than looking at a screenshot.

Comment: Not only that, but Browsershots queue these days is just way too long.

Answer (score 5):

Safari uses 'mac' fonts, but Chrome would use 'Windows' fonts.  I've noticed that there can sometimes be problems where using a font like Arial, it shows up fine in firefox/chrome/ie, but on Safari, it can cause a line to wrap because the font is slightly bigger.

Comment: Something may be wrong if your site depends on pixel-perfect accuracy (not talking about CSS standards here), especially with fonts...  HTML was designed to simply not care what was done with the rendering.  Regardless, you may forget to include "sans-serif" in your font-family list or something.

Comment: Wish I could +1 comments. stranger is right, let the content flow or give enough space (+/-10%) for different browsers. Remember, remember, non-PC browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only for your fonts and JavaScripts.

I have noticed some of the default fonts are smaller on Safari then Chrome, also Chrome uses the V8 JavaScript engine which has caused some people problems, especially if you have a lot of form logic.

Comment: "For 99% of the problems"? Then, that would be no, unless you're relying on statistical sampling rather than exhaustive testing (which isn't necessarily a bad thing, but you should be aware of its limitations). Still, if 99% is right, that's pretty damn good statistical sampling...

Comment: Just for the record, I've reworded the question now, so this "yes" answer actually means "no, you don't need to test Safari".

Answer (score 1):

yes.

Oh, you wanted more detail?  Simply, Chrome and Safari have a lot of different features in their implementations, and Safari is pretty widely used. If you expect the general public, and particularly those of us who work on Macs, to use your application, it would behoove you to test in the Safari browser.

Comment: Your one-liner and expansion don't seem to match - are you saying you should or shouldn't test in Safari as well as Chrome?

Comment: His answer seems pretty clear to me - in both parts he's saying you should test in both

Answer (score 1):

Yes, safari and chrome even though they are using webkit the two versions of webkit that are being used are significantly different. So you need to restest.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, No.  You can't assume that because it works in one it will definitely work in all cases in the other.  Sure, 99% of the time, it might be the same - but 99% isn't 100% - at least, it wasn't last time I checked.  Call me a pedantic git if you like.

Comment: You changed the question:  Yes, you need to test in both browsers!